# Design an iOS app opening a webapp using in app web Browser on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, web-applications, uiwebview

Currently I was tasked to build an simple in iOS to open a WebApp.. I know this is dumb but this is the task and I was looking for good design to solve this problem.
Here are several requirements:

1. I only have the link to the webapp <- this app is fully functioned
2. When you open the app, you should be able to see the webapp in fullscreen without any navigation control <- just like the native app. All interaction should be handled inside the app, which means clicking on a link will not open the link in safari but in the app.

Can you guys give me some recommendations? any library to look at??
I was thinking of just building it use the UIWebview, haven't started yet ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use UIWebView:

```
 UIWebView webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0 width, height)];
 [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
 [self.view addSubview:webView];
```

A couple other notes:
If you are the one developing the app in the future and want to use web technologies to develop a hybrid app, you could look at a platform like PhoneGap.

Additionally, if the web app doesn't act like a native app and you plan on publishing it to the App store you may run into issues getting it approved with Apple.

Comment: Thank you for the notes: they need the app in two weeks so I hope this will get approved by apple :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a `-UIwebView` inside the app should be enough, take a look at the [UIWebview documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)